# How to restrict moderators to only access a limited set of users?

Tags: 7, views, users

I have 2 user roles: Moderator and Company. Each Moderator has a set of companies; for example:

- Moderator A owns Company d, e, anf f
- Moderator B own Company g, h, and i

When moderator A logs in, I want that moderator can **only** see Company d, e, and f. I want to use a view.

How can I achieve this? How can I restrict each moderator to see those companies (which, I repeat, are user accounts) they own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module which is like a "little brother" of [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). It only started in D7 and with a D8 version in the pipeline. Personally I'm more and more considering/using it as a potential alternative for the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module. And since it is all Entity based, there are lots of ways it can be used in combination with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module also.

Specific to your question here, I think what is going to help you a lot is the **Group member profiles** submodule, which you can use to create multiple fieldable member profiles and which can be attached to a member.

For way more details about this module, refer to:

- Its [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972) pages, such as the [Group HowTos](https://www.drupal.org/node/2692869) subpage of it.
- The interesting comment #2 to the issue titled "[What's the difference is between Group Types and Groups and how to configure them?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2695467#comment-11033567)".
- [Integrations of Group with other modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603130).
- My answer to "[How to only allow a user to edit his/her own users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190003/how-to-only-allow-a-user-to-edit-his-her-own-users/190013#190013)".

Also, as per your comment below (= "*Can you tell me if it works with views? I would like to display in a view all the companies attached to the user (Moderator) that is logged in.*"): I suggest you have a look at comment nr 2 in the issue about "[How to list groups in a view?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2694743#comment-11014487)", which even includes a view in export format you may want to have a look at.

**Note**: Your question doesn't specify which version you are using, but this answer applies for both D7 and D8.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll take a look at this promising module. Before I try it, can you tell me if it works with views? I would like to display in a view all the companies attached to the user (Moderator) that is logged in.

Comment: Hi again. I'm having trouble to understand the views... I created a group type and a role "Moderator" inside. I added 3 users to the group, and one user has the role "Moderator". In the view, I want to display only the members of the group taht belong to the logged in user. I tried to use relationships with views but I'm missing something. Here's how my view looks like: http://imgur.com/jBUzG3Y

Comment: The views part was solved here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2699371#comment-11034833

Answer (score 2):

If moderators are creating the Company nodes themselves, you will probably be best off with the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module.

If Company nodes are created by administrators, you could use the [Node access user reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) field to reference the moderators. They would then get the necessary view permissions.

Let me know if I missed your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The thing is, Company is not a content type that creates nodes. It's a role that creates users.

I installed entity reference and I told the "company d", that its moderator is "Moderator A". Now I need to tell the user "company d" that it can only be seen by Moderator A. Can I do this with nodeaccess_user reference? I hope I'm explaining this well

Comment: I think I get it now; so you want to grant Moderator users to see only Company users they have created?

Comment: yes! But the users are created by admin